# I got 5 ellipse parameters, 4 of which are coordinates of 2 focus points, what would the last one be? And how can I get the ellipse function?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I am working on a machine learning project processing [fundus images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundus_photography).

I have an image dataset, each image in which comes with a 5-number tuple called "ellipse parameters". However, the dataset is poorly documented and I can't figure out what the fifth parameter is.

Here are some examples of the five numbers:

img1:`195,199,222,227,0`

img2:`168,171,209,214,-39`

img3:`323,344,409,420,14`

I <del>am pretty sure</del> believe that the first four numbers are the coordinates of the two focus points (because their locations on the corresponding images make sense). But the fifth number is weird -- it doesn't look like either the sum of distance to the two focus points or the eccentricity.

**My Question:**

**So, what could this number be? And how can I get the ellipse function ?**

---

**Update #1:**

The dataset contains multiple (image,txtfile) pairs.

In the txtfile, there are some numbers as listed below:

I) a center point (x,y coordinates, 2 numbers)

II) 16 boundary points (x,y coordinates, 16*2 = 32 numbers, they can form an polygon)

III) "ellipse parameters" mentioned above (5 numbers)

**In order to better understand how these numbers work, I did the following:**

1) draw the center point (the blue point in the following images),

2) draw the polygon by connecting the 16 points (the green boundary),

3) draw a line segment between the two ***focus points*** (the green line, **however, I am now not sure whether they are the two focus points**)

4) print the 5th number on the left upper corner of that image.

**Now, I have generated images like this:**

[img_285](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Wci.png), and its corresponding data from its txt file:

I) center point: 255, 251

II) 16 boundary points: (420, 251), (413, 316), (380, 376), (323, 416), (255, 425), (191, 405), (140, 366), (106, 313), (90, 251), (97, 186), (130, 126), (187, 86), (255, 77), (319, 97), (370, 136), (404, 189)

III) "ellipse parameters": `255, 251, 322, 357, -29`

I notice that **the first focus point** (maybe it will turn out to be something else, but at least for now I still call (255,251) and (322,357) the two focus points) **is always the same as the center point**, and that's why in the images you will always see the line segment starts from the blue point.

Here are some more images with their "ellipse parameters":

[img_290](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V9PW.png) : `231, 239, 311, 290, 39`

[img_291](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5g09.png) : `206, 196, 297, 314, -134`

[img_293](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYIlZ.png) : `206, 182, 168, 211, -21`

[img_294](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goUtU.png) : `170, 158, 158, 242, 0`

[img_317](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1grv.png) : `231, 255, 285, 260, -43`

[img_332](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHshS.png) : `287, 288, 283, 323, 23`

After checking these images, I am now even more confused. I feel like the (3rd number, 4th number) pair may not be a focus point.

Why would I think so? I don't want to talk too much about Ophthalmology. **In short, if there is a way to interpret these "ellipse parameters" and draw an ellipse, that ellipse should locate within the polygon, or at least not exceed the boundary of the polygon too much.**

However, in img_291, the "focus point" (3rd,4th), or (297, 314), is out of the boundary of the polygon (as the line segmentation exceeds the polygon). If I draw an ellipse with these two points((206, 196) and (297, 314)) as foci, that ellipse must have a pretty large part outside the polygon. This perhaps indicates that (297, 314) is not a focus point at all, thus there will be 3 parameters (instead of 1 ) that I need to understand.

Of course, img_291 could be an outlier that should be excluded. **No matter which is the case ((3rd,4th) be a focus point or not), how should I interpret the 5 ellipse parameters?**

Comment: This is a tantalizing question, and I’d like to help. Are the first four numbers $(x,y,x',y')$ ? If so, your ellipses look all to be oriented with axis roughly $45^\circ$ to the horizontal. I really wish you had given us the data sets and not just the $5$-parameter lists.

Comment: @Lubin I have added some images with their "ellipse parameters", please have a look. They are not necessarily oriented at roughly 45 degree. And by the way, I still believe the first two numbers are a pair of coordinates, but now I am less sure about the 3rd and 4th number than before.

Comment: I was hoping that the fifth no. could be the rotation, clockwise from upwards, but that was wrong. Geometrically, it makes best sense for a point associated to an ellipse to be the center. But they’ve told you the center, yes? and does the first pair of numbers really seem to be a focus? If you’d like, I’d be happy to chat with you by e-mail. I think you can get my web page from my profile, and the page has my e-mail.